# 3d Plotting / Spatial with Flash for Web Site using Dynamic Data

Tags: flash, charts, graph

Looking for a flash component for a website that has some characteristics of a graph but a little more specialized.

I want to be able to plot points in an area and give the user the ability to zoom in , zoom out and move around.

A 3d line graph which give me the ability to turn off the plot lines and just leave the points would be acceptable as a stop gap long as the user can move the graph around and zoom in and out.

I would be generating the data for the graph / plot from a backend database.

Any recommendations greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My math skills are something close to inexistent, but I've seen something that might help you on the [flashandmath.com](http://www.flashandmath.com/advanced/contours/index.html) website.